# Xamarin Android: Using IntentService to listen remote communication

Tags: xamarin, communication, intentservice, android-intentservice

I have two devices which I need to have one device to be a listener to the other. E.g the first device has to be signal via UDP protocol to second device to load an application (with my custom made mouse/keyboard) to control the first device).

Even though if using IntentService to do the listening, the service still can be killed by the device if memory went low. From the document, I can use redelivery intent flag to restart the service. How does the phone know how much memory i need for that service to restart.

Comment: It doesn't, but if it needs more memory on start up than is available, Android should kill other apps/services that are no longer being used to make room for your service. And again, as your service runs and perhaps needs even more memory, Android will kill more apps/services if it can to accommodate your service's needs.

Comment: hmm but many services are running in the background how does system know which one need or not. E.g. My intentService require to listen udp packet coming in so it can not be killed but this service probably doesn't take too much memory since it only listening and start the application appropriately. I think if it get killed, I would have a alarm manager periodically checks is the service still alive if not it start the service.

Comment: You probably want to have it `START_STICKY`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY Secondly you can read about what processes get priority and what doesn't here: https://medium.com/google-developers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f#.9dbag1479